# grep line with exact pattern in first column

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have this script :

```
while read line; do grep $line my_annot | awk '{print $2}' ; done < foo.txt
```

But it doesn't return what I want.

The problem is that in foo.txt, when I have for instance Contig1, the script will return the column 2 of the file my_annot even if the pattern found is Contig12 and not Contig1 only!

I tried with $ at the end of the pattern but the problem is that it corresponds to end of line while this expression I search is in column 1 and therefore not end of line.

How can I tell to search this EXACT pattern and not those that contain this pattern?

####### ANSWER :

My script is :

```
annot='/home/mu/myannot'
awk 'NR == FNR { line[$0]; next } $1 in line { print $2 }' $1 $annot > out
```

It allows me to give the list of expression I want to find as first argument doing ./myscript.sh mylist

And I redirect the result in a file called out.

Thank you guys !!!!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the regex in `^` and `$`?

Comment: Why not just `awk '$1=="Contig1"{print $2}' foo.txt` instead of all that looping and grepping?

Comment: Isn't `grep -w` or `grep --word-regexp` what you need?

Comment: We need to see an example of both of your input files as well as the desired output. This problem can almost certainly be solved in a single invocation of awk.

Comment: I disagree with your approach here but to answer the regex part of this question `grep -P ` or `awk` with no while loop can be used to solve this. A simple regex that only matches `Contig1` and not `Contig12` using inclusion could be `Contig1\b` where `\b` is a word boundary or `Contig1\s` where `\s` is white-space using exclusion it could be `Contig1(?!\d)` where `(?!\d)` is not followed by a number.

Comment: I would also suggest using a regex tester like this `https://regex101.com/r/bN9bU2/2` to help yourself answer these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use awk to do the whole thing:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { line[$0]; next } $1 in line { print $2 }' foo.txt my_annot
```

This reads each line of `foo.txt`, setting a key in the array `line`, then prints the second column of any lines whose first column exactly matches one of the keys in the array.

Of course I have made a guess that the format of your data is the same as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a file like

```
Contig1         hugo
Contig12        paul
```

right?

Then this will help:

```
awk '$1~/^Contig1$/ {print $2}' foo.txt
```

Comment: or just `$1=="Contig1"`.

Comment: yeah... you are right - would be a bit more performant and less cryptic ;)

Comment: OK but how do you combine with while read line ? Because Contig1 is a line among others in a file that I want to read. $1=="$line" ??

Comment: `awk` is all you need. `awk` reads the file line by line. Neither a while loop nor `grep` is needed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
while read line; do grep -w $line my_annot | awk '{print $2}' ; done < foo.txt
```

But it's not 100% clear (because of a lack of example data) whether it will work in all cases.

Comment: This is what @Carcamano suggested in the comments, by the way.